# How to preload images with multiple srcset with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, image, caching, preload

I'm trying to build a script to preload images with jQuery, for a small application I'm working on.

I've read different tutorials and right now I managed to have it working like this:

```
var imageList = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];
$.each(imageList, function (index, imageName) {
    var $img = $('<img>')[0];
    $img.onload = function () {
        console.log('loaded');
    };
    $img.src = imgPath + imageName;
}
```

This works fine. I load the images from an array I prepare, I then create all the `img` tags and then append them in the DOM where needed.

I'm wondering now, though, how can I do something similar if I have images with multiple `srcset`.

Let's say I have 3 sizes for each image, but they could be more, normally I would put something like this in the html:

```
<img srcset="large.jpg 1024w,
      medium.jpg 640w,
      small.jpg 320w"
   sizes="(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw"
   src="small.jpg">
```

Now, how shall I apply the preloading to this?

1) I could preload all the sizes for each image in Javascript, but this would be pointless, because the whole purpose of having multiple srcset is to load just one
2) I could put the `img` tag in the DOM, let the browser choose the only size needed and load from Javascript.

The problem with the second option is that the browser is loading the images from the DOM, so why loading them again in Javascript? It's possible that I am completely wrong about this and maybe I'm missing something. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same idea that you had in your script, but instead set the `sizes` and `srcset` attributes.

```
const image = new Image()
image.onload = () => console.log('loaded')
image.sizes = '(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw' 

// This will trigger the browser to start loading the appropriate picture
image.srcset = `
  large.jpg 1024w,
  medium.jpg 640w,
  small.jpg 320w
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you detect the browser width in Javascript, and use that to load the proper images? You could have one array for small images, one for medium, and one for large.

Even better, if you'd name the images such that the size is a suffix (image1_small.png and image1_large.png) you'd only need one array, and just append the correct suffix.

Alternatively, keep separate directories, small/ large/ etc and just give the proper path, according to window width.